# If there is no SecurityManager found does this mean I cannot setProperty?

Tags: java, ssl, redhat, executable-jar, java-security

I feel that the issue I'm having is due to how things are suppose to be configured which I'm not sure of how that is to be.

When running an executable .jar file on our dev systems we are setting via System.setProperty the location of the keystore and truststore. This works as we are able to communicate to the database server and get the data.

When running an executable .jar file on our production systems we are NOT able to set via System.setProperty the location of the keystore and truststore. This is apparent when debugging is on and shows 1. Nothing for our keystore and 2. The wrong location for the truststore so we are NOT able to communicate to the database server.

I have been trying to set the value via the java code as well as passing the values on the call to the jar itself, i.e. `java -jar -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/keystore` etc.

Can someone provide any possible things I should be looking into?
I've also been looking into the java.policy and java.security files but both have virtually nothing in them and we have nobody in house to go to for an answer.

-- update --
On the production system using the debug there is nothing set for the keystore location and the truststore path appears to be pointing to some other location.

Comment: Maybe the paths are different on your production server? (You're saying that you have "the wrong location" for the truststore, implying that you did change the location of the truststore from the default. So setting the property worked. Which suggests that the paths are wrong)

Comment: I'm sorry let me clarify further above regarding the production server.

Comment: Is there other code on the production server that uses those `javax.net.ssl.*` system properties (is there anything that initialises the default `SSLContext`), even implicitly (i.e. is there anything else that makes an SSL/TLS connection without using its own custom `SSLContext`)?

Comment: what does your code to get the property look like? No SecurityManager (i.e. `System.getSecurityManager() == null`) simply means that your code can do whatever operations it wants -- including `System.getProperty()`.  If the SecurityManager is **not** null, then the permissions of your code is restricted by the policy file set in place.